# How to put circles over a checkerboard?

Tags: java, arrays

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I am a beginner in java and our teacher doesn't explain things too well.  I understand how to create a checkerboard in java.  Next I am supposed to put white circles over all the black squares so it looks like a game of checkers.  It doesn't have to move.

I figured I would use the same logic as I did with the rectangles, but then all of the circles were way off and didn't match up with the black squares at all.

```
int sqSize = 50;  
int gridSize = 500; 
int n;  
int[][] grid; 

public void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);  
  noLoop();  
  n = gridSize/sqSize; 
  grid = new int[n][n];
}

void draw()
{
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      stroke(0);
      if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
      {
        fill(255, 0, 0); 
        rect(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2);
      } else {
        fill(0, 0, 0); 
        rect(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2); 
        fill(255);
        ellipse(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2);
        //this is what I tried, but failed.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the circles to be exactly aligned  over it, like actual checker pieces, but the actual output is the circles not spaced out enough and on both squares.

Comment: I am sorry, I swear I clicked javascript.  I feel really bad.  Sorry.

Comment: Oh it said java when I got here so I was confused, and changed it back, but it changed it again itself? This is my first time posting.

Comment: Thank you! It's a big help, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the solution to your problem, but I'm not sure what the functions that you're calling are. Do you know if you're using java with any add-ons or frameworks? Specifically what class does the ellipse() method belong to?

Comment: @ngood97 he is using Processing, a language that I like to call "visual Java". https://processing.org

Comment: @ngood97 it's okay I already got the answer! But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue for you. You needed to specify how the local (0,0) is defined for a shape. I changed the ellipse to consider (0,0) to be the top left corner, and now it draws as intended.

```
int sqSize = 50;  
int gridSize = 500; 
int n;  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
int[][] grid; 

public void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);  
  noLoop();  
  n = gridSize/sqSize; 
  grid = new int[n][n];

  ellipseMode(CORNER);
}

void draw()
{
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      stroke(0);
      if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
      {
        fill(255, 0, 0); 
        rect(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2);
      } else {
        fill(0, 0, 0); 
        rect(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2); 
        fill(255);
        ellipse(row*sqSize, col*sqSize, sqSize-2, sqSize-2);
        //this is what I tried, but failed.
      }
    }
  }
}
```